# JQuery: Bind multiple triggers from multiple elements to one event

Tags: jquery, function, triggers, toggle

I've been trawling through the internet trying to find a solution to this, but all I've found are slight variations on multiple elements/events/triggers and not this specific problem.

The situation is I have a search button which, when clicked toggled the visibility of the search input. I want to be able to toggle the search closed again by clicking the button but also when the search input focus blurs.

My current code is:

```
function toggleSearch() {
$("#search").animate({
        width: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "slow",function() { $(this).focus(); });
$("#searchButton").parent('li').siblings().animate({
        width: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "slow");
}

$("#searchButton").click(toggleSearch);
$("#search").blur(toggleSearch);
```

The problem here is that if you click the button to toggle the search closed again, it also counts as the input blurring so fires the function twice and the search closes and reopens. So basically I need something that would do this:

```
$("#searchButton").click() or $("#search").blur() {
    toggleSearch();
}
```

I'd also like to change the function of the button from toggling it open/closed to submitting the search depending on whether there is a value in the search input. But from what I've experienced with this I'm not sure of the syntax to use that will work.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hGgc9/

Comment: fiddle would be helpful

Comment: My bad, here: http://jsfiddle.net/hGgc9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an animation is currently running by using:

```
function toggleSearch() {
    if (!$("#search").is(":animated")) {
        $("#search").animate({
                width: "toggle",
                opacity: "toggle"
            }, "slow",function() { $(this).focus(); });
    }
}

$("#searchButton").parent('li').siblings().animate({
     width: "toggle",
     opacity: "toggle"
}, "slow");

$("#searchButton").click(toggleSearch);
$("#search").blur(toggleSearch);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hGgc9/3/

Comment: That is perfect, the search button siblings should be within the toggle function too but that is exactly what I need. I had come up with a solution that worked but yours is much cleaner! Thank you